# Click event repeats 4 times

Tags: javascript, jquery

### My code

```
var post = {};
post.DivPostContent = $('.content');
post.DivPostContent.live({
    mouseenter:
        function()
        {
            var post_id = $(this).attr('data-post_id');
            var content_id = $('#content' + '_' + post_id);
            var link = $('#link' + '_' + post_id);
            content_id.find('.post_ratings').hide();
            content_id.find('.post_actions').show();
            //I removed the click event on a whim, i have no clue why it works
            link.unbind('click');
            link.click(function(){
                post.link_action(post_id);

            });


        },
    mouseleave:
        function()
        {
            //does something


        }
});

post.link_action = function(){
//Does some Ajax request
}
```

Before i unbinded the click event from "Link" it called "post.link_action" four times, i was trying to get my head around why it does that. After hours of reading through my code again and again, i thought to myself, let's try removing the click event and i mistakenly put that line in the wrong place(out of frustration i guess). I ran the code, and viola! it worked! How? I have no clue.

Now my question is, why does unbinding the click event before adding it stop the process from repeating itself? I really would like to know why.
Thanks.

Comment: Every time it entered the function, the mouseenter, it would attach a new listener to the element, not replace it. By doing an unbind, it removed the previous click bindings. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ZHgfS/) for an example. The click binding does not replace the current binding, it simply adds more handlers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because every time your mouse enter the object post.DivPostContent it's binding a new click event to your link object; it triggered 4 times because you moused over 4 times.

forget .live & .click; use .on instead and bind one time & outside your mouseenter event or if you insist to bind it in there use a .off before

```
 $elem.off("click").on("click",function() {});
```

but do it once and outside your mousenter

Comment: Thanks, i understand it now :) Instresting, what's $elem?

Comment: it's whatever jquery object you want to bind off & then on with

Answer (score 1):

> Now my question is, why does unbinding the click event before adding it stop the process from repeating itself?

The code:

```
link.click(function(){
    post.link_action(post_id);
});
```

Adds a callback to the `click` event, if you register multiple times, like in your case `onmouseenter` you will end up with the same event firing multiple times.

The `unbind` function removes any previous callbacks to the specific event, so this why the callback fires only one time.

By the way, unless your jQuery version is 1.4.3 or less you shouldn't be unsing `live`.
Use `on` which is available from version **1.7**  ore `delegate` which is avaiable from version **1.4.4.**

Comment: I get it now, thanks :) Oh, i initially used .on() on this same piece of code but it didn't work, that's why i resorted to .live() :(

Comment: @SaffronHarris, I suggest you to return to `on` and learn how to use it. You probably just didn't use a selector and thus didn't create a delegate event.

Comment: Hmm, does that mean i might have to change to "hover" if i use on? WHat's so bad about .live anyways?

Comment: @SaffronHarris, you can still use what event you want. [What's wrong with live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)